# Set cluster core per rule in Snakemake

Tags: snakemake

I need to download hundreds of large files, and run each of them through my snakemake pipeline. The file download is fast compared to my downstream pipeline. I'd like to limit the number of parallel downloads to 5, but allow the downsteam processing to use 100 cores. In snakemake, is there a way to limit the number of cores used by a certain rule? I picture 5 cores constantly grabbing data, while my other cores are working on the data I've already downloaded. If I run snakemake as usual with 100 cores, it will try to download all files at once, and overload the server. 
I already tried to do it by adding 'threads:1' to the rule but It does not work as it is supposed to. I suppose that by adding 'threads:1' to the rule, it should return the same results as when '-j 1' option is used in the command line for that rule, but they return different results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `resources` to limit how many rules can run in parallel. You can name the resources as you please, see [resources documentation](http://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/rules.html#resources). Here is an example using the name `download_streams`.

Snakefile:

```
rule r1:
    output: touch("{field}.txt")
    resources: download_streams=1
    shell:
        "sleep 2; "
        "echo $(date '+%H:%M:%S') Finished downloading {output}"
```

Running `snakemake  download_{1..10}.txt --resources download_streams=2 -j 10 > log.txt` gives the following in `log.txt`

```
12:00:58 Finished downloading download_1.txt
12:00:58 Finished downloading download_5.txt
12:01:00 Finished downloading download_6.txt
12:01:00 Finished downloading download_8.txt
12:01:02 Finished downloading download_9.txt
12:01:02 Finished downloading download_10.txt
12:01:04 Finished downloading download_3.txt
12:01:04 Finished downloading download_2.txt
12:01:06 Finished downloading download_4.txt
12:01:06 Finished downloading download_7.txt
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It works but it is very unintuitive. First, The 'Threads' option bases on its description is clearly designed for the purpose of limiting the number of available cores for that rule. Why it does not work as it is supposed to? and Second, with resources, how snakemake figure out whether by resources we mean number of cores or available memory, just by the difference in the values??

Comment: You misunderstand what thread does. It tells snakemake how many cores an instance of a rule will use. By setting threads to 1, you tell snakemake that it can run up to 100 instances of this rule in parallel (with --job 100). If you want to limit how many instances of each rule can be run in parallel, you have to use a unique ressource for each rule.